# Connecting MetaMask with parity

Tags: parity, metamask

I have configured parity to listen on an IP (and not on localhost) and verified that port 8545 opens when I start parity. I can reach the parity UI via a browser but I cannot connect MetaMask to parity.

I checked connecting via https and http but it both does not work. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: use --jsonrpc-cors=[URL] option to enable cors from specific  domain. And  --jsonrpc-cors=["all"] to enable cors from all.